# Powershell print get-physicaldisk to a text file

Tags: powershell

I need to get a list of kinds of hard drives all our company computer's use.  I figured the best way is to run a startup script that outputs the info to a text file.

The problem I'm having is when printing to the text file. The get-physicaldisk works in the console, but when printing to a text file it prints something different.

```
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$disk = get-physicaldisk | format-table -Auto deviceID,Size,BusType,MediaType,Model

New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path . -Name $name'.txt' -Value "$name `r`n$disk" -Force
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can out the product as a string. by piping to  `| out-string`

```
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$disk = get-physicaldisk | format-table -Auto deviceID,Size,BusType,MediaType,Model | out-string
New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path . -Name $name'.txt' -Value "$name `r`n$($disk.ToString())" -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to redirect the output from `Get-PhysicalDisk` to the file:

```
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$output_file_path = '~\temp\drives.txt'

Get-PhysicalDisk |
 Format-Table -Auto DeviceID, Size, BusType, MediaType, Model |
 Out-File -FilePath $output_file_path -Encoding 'ASCII' -Append
```

You'll probably want to replace that `Format-Table` with an `ExportTo-CSV` otherwise you'll have a fun time processing all that output later.